How can I recover a RAID10 array using mdadm (on Synology NAS) after power loss/surge when disks have read errors and are lacking raid superblock?
I had a power loss/surge event and it's left the RAID10 on my Synology diskstation in an unusable state. The array is 8x 6TB disks in RAID10. I have SSH access to the NAS and have performed some basic analysis.
Disks 1-3 are fine. Disks 5-8 show un-correctable read errors for one or two LBAs (all around the same position). Disks 5-8 also have no RAID superblock anymore. Fdisk can see all the partitions on all the disks.
I have been able to ascertain the UUIDs of the members which no longer have a superblock. My gut feeling is that I can recover much of this data with some small data loss localised to some files or directories, but I will need to recreate the array. As this array is so large, I don't really have the swing-space to do a full clone.
Please also spare me the reminders about backups. I had some of the data backed up. The bulk of it was not. There is some data which I really care to retrieve that was not backed up. I fully realise my error. I don't want lessons on whether I should take backups and how to detract from the question and the data recovery steps. Thank you.
Please see the following useful output (mdadm, smartctl etc):
smartctl self-test log (example for bad disks, truncated due to post limit):
EDIT: After checking one of the disks that was reporting read errors on the Synology smartctl test on my desktop PC, the test passed without read errors. I then replaced it back in the nas and checked again, and the nas again sees the read errors. I rather suspect the SATA backplane card is busted on ports 5 through 8. The device is just 2 months out of warranty but Synology are going to see if they have a replacement card in stock for purchase.
EDIT2: Does anyone know if I can take the first (or later) half of the RAID10 disks (they were added in numerical order) and attempt a recovery based on a RAID1 in any way? This would reduce my blast radius of attempt, reduce the amount of storage I need to store ddrescue dumps, and essentially give me two chances at recovery. 3 of the 4 disks that I believe comprise one mirror, are marked good and fully readable. Losing one sector on the 4th drive is surely not a game over situation?

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%     27829         9437200
# 2  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     27826         9437192
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     17628         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16884         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16164         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15420         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14700         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13908         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13164         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     12420         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     11700         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     10955         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     10235         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      9491         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8748         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8027         -
#17  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7283         -
#18  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6563         -
#19  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5820         -
#20  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5148         -
#21  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4404         -

smartctl 6.5 (build date Sep 26 2022) [x86_64-linux-4.4.302+] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%     27828         9437192
# 2  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     27826         9437192
# 3  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%     27825         9437200
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     17628         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16884         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16164         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15420         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14700         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13908         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13164         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     12420         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     11700         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     10955         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     10235         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      9491         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8748         -
#17  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8027         -
#18  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7283         -
#19  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6563         -
#20  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5820         -
#21  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5148         -

smartctl 6.5 (build date Sep 26 2022) [x86_64-linux-4.4.302+] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%     27828         9437192
# 2  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     27826         9437192
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     17628         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16884         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16164         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15420         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14700         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13908         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13164         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     12420         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     11700         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     10955         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     10235         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      9491         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8747         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8027         -
#17  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7283         -
#18  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6563         -
#19  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5820         -
#20  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5148         -
#21  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4404         -

smartctl 6.5 (build date Sep 26 2022) [x86_64-linux-4.4.302+] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%     27828         9437192
# 2  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     27826         9437192
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     17628         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16884         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16164         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15420         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14700         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13908         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13164         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     12420         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     11700         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     10955         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     10235         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      9491         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8747         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8027         -
#17  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7283         -
#18  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6563         -
#19  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5820         -
#20  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5148         -
#21  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4404         -

smartctl 6.5 (build date Sep 26 2022) [x86_64-linux-4.4.302+] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%     27826         9437192
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     17628         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16884         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     16164         -
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     15420         -
# 6  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14700         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13908         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     13164         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     12420         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     11700         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     10955         -
#12  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     10235         -
#13  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      9491         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8747         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8027         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      7283         -
#17  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      6563         -
#18  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5820         -
#19  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      5148         -
#20  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4404         -
#21  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      3660         -

mdadm examine
root@nas:~# for disk in {1..8}; do mdadm --examine /dev/sata${disk}p3; done
/dev/sata1p3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : e0dbf189:7ea6486d:781cfdbe:7460653e
           Name : syn_nas:2
  Creation Time : Mon Jul  5 12:42:12 2021
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 8

 Avail Dev Size : 11711401120 (5584.43 GiB 5996.24 GB)
     Array Size : 23422802176 (22337.72 GiB 23984.95 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 11711401088 (5584.43 GiB 5996.24 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1968 sectors, after=32 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 5b7d825b:a8f72b91:80b9f543:f61f4901

    Update Time : Wed Oct  2 18:52:24 2024
       Checksum : a567977c - correct
         Events : 1064

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 0
   Array State : AAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sata2p3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : e0dbf189:7ea6486d:781cfdbe:7460653e
           Name : syn_nas:2
  Creation Time : Mon Jul  5 12:42:12 2021
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 8

 Avail Dev Size : 11711401120 (5584.43 GiB 5996.24 GB)
     Array Size : 23422802176 (22337.72 GiB 23984.95 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 11711401088 (5584.43 GiB 5996.24 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1968 sectors, after=32 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : 6598be06:4f6cdcb0:4c2ede80:b8634a8e

    Update Time : Wed Oct  2 18:52:24 2024
       Checksum : 3a3ddfbd - correct
         Events : 1064

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/sata3p3:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x0
     Array UUID : e0dbf189:7ea6486d:781cfdbe:7460653e
           Name : syn_nas:2
  Creation Time : Mon Jul  5 12:42:12 2021
     Raid Level : raid10
   Raid Devices : 8

 Avail Dev Size : 11711401120 (5584.43 GiB 5996.24 GB)
     Array Size : 23422802176 (22337.72 GiB 23984.95 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 11711401088 (5584.43 GiB 5996.24 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
   Unused Space : before=1968 sectors, after=32 sectors
          State : active
    Device UUID : b249bbb5:5cd44246:86bc5f22:164682a4

    Update Time : Wed Oct  2 18:52:24 2024
       Checksum : 365a69b0 - correct
         Events : 1064

         Layout : near=2
     Chunk Size : 64K

   Device Role : Active device 2
   Array State : AAAAAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sata4p3.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sata5p3.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sata6p3.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sata7p3.
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sata8p3.

spacetool_synoblock_enum (synology tool)
root@nas:~# spacetool --synoblock-enum
****** Syno-Block of /dev/sata1 ******
Version: 7
Capability: 0x2
Features: 1
Space Type: Storage Pool
Space Path: @storage_pool
Reuse ID: [reuse_1]
Descriptions: [raid10]
Volume Description: []
Cross EBox: FALSE
Limited RAID Group: SYNO_24
Cache Info:
        Cache Mode: Read
        Cache Type: SSD Cache
        SSD UUID: [470b94ec:85ecef3e:3244234e:bf658f97]
        Cache size: 429496729600
        Shared Cache ID: 0
        Allocated Cache Sub ID: 0
        SSD ID: 1
        Target Space UUID: [83OFdO-o3zP-JVXO-N841-vfRv-dM6x-AdacPT]
        Skip sequential IO: 1
        Max Degrade Flush: 0
        APM Flush Done: 0
        Allowed Drop Cache: 0
PV count: 1
VG path: /dev/vg1
VG UUID: [rJ0X3K-x3cp-Zw8G-0f2U-8BU2-D3VN-y1vlMk]
RAID UUID: [e0dbf189:7ea6486d:781cfdbe:7460653e]

****** Syno-Block of /dev/sata2 ******
Version: 7
Capability: 0x2
Features: 1
Space Type: Storage Pool
Space Path: @storage_pool
Reuse ID: [reuse_1]
Descriptions: [raid10]
Volume Description: []
Cross EBox: FALSE
Limited RAID Group: SYNO_24
Cache Info:
        Cache Mode: Read
        Cache Type: SSD Cache
        SSD UUID: [470b94ec:85ecef3e:3244234e:bf658f97]
        Cache size: 429496729600
        Shared Cache ID: 0
        Allocated Cache Sub ID: 0
        SSD ID: 1
        Target Space UUID: [83OFdO-o3zP-JVXO-N841-vfRv-dM6x-AdacPT]
        Skip sequential IO: 1
        Max Degrade Flush: 0
        APM Flush Done: 0
        Allowed Drop Cache: 0
PV count: 1
VG path: /dev/vg1
VG UUID: [rJ0X3K-x3cp-Zw8G-0f2U-8BU2-D3VN-y1vlMk]
RAID UUID: [e0dbf189:7ea6486d:781cfdbe:7460653e]

****** Syno-Block of /dev/sata3 ******
Version: 7
Capability: 0x2
Features: 1
Space Type: Storage Pool
Space Path: @storage_pool
Reuse ID: [reuse_1]
Descriptions: [raid10]
Volume Description: []
Cross EBox: FALSE
Limited RAID Group: SYNO_24
Cache Info:
        Cache Mode: Read
        Cache Type: SSD Cache
        SSD UUID: [470b94ec:85ecef3e:3244234e:bf658f97]
        Cache size: 429496729600
        Shared Cache ID: 0
        Allocated Cache Sub ID: 0
        SSD ID: 1
        Target Space UUID: [83OFdO-o3zP-JVXO-N841-vfRv-dM6x-AdacPT]
        Skip sequential IO: 1
        Max Degrade Flush: 0
        APM Flush Done: 0
        Allowed Drop Cache: 0
PV count: 1
VG path: /dev/vg1
VG UUID: [rJ0X3K-x3cp-Zw8G-0f2U-8BU2-D3VN-y1vlMk]
RAID UUID: [e0dbf189:7ea6486d:781cfdbe:7460653e]

****** Syno-Block of /dev/sata4 ******
Version: 7
Capability: 0x2
Features: 1
Space Type: Storage Pool
Space Path: @storage_pool
Reuse ID: [reuse_1]
Descriptions: [raid10]
Volume Description: []
Cross EBox: FALSE
Limited RAID Group: SYNO_24
Cache Info:
        Cache Mode: Read
        Cache Type: SSD Cache
        SSD UUID: [470b94ec:85ecef3e:3244234e:bf658f97]
        Cache size: 429496729600
        Shared Cache ID: 0
        Allocated Cache Sub ID: 0
        SSD ID: 1
        Target Space UUID: [83OFdO-o3zP-JVXO-N841-vfRv-dM6x-AdacPT]
        Skip sequential IO: 1
        Max Degrade Flush: 0
        APM Flush Done: 0
        Allowed Drop Cache: 0
PV count: 1
VG path: /dev/vg1
VG UUID: [rJ0X3K-x3cp-Zw8G-0f2U-8BU2-D3VN-y1vlMk]
RAID UUID: [e0dbf189:7ea6486d:781cfdbe:7460653e]

****** Syno-Block of /dev/sata5 ******
Version: 7
Capability: 0x2
Features: 1
Space Type: Storage Pool
Space Path: @storage_pool
Reuse ID: [reuse_1]
Descriptions: [raid10]
Volume Description: []
Cross EBox: FALSE
Limited RAID Group: SYNO_24
Cache Info:
        Cache Mode: Read
        Cache Type: SSD Cache
        SSD UUID: [470b94ec:85ecef3e:3244234e:bf658f97]
        Cache size: 429496729600
        Shared Cache ID: 0
        Allocated Cache Sub ID: 0
        SSD ID: 1
        Target Space UUID: [83OFdO-o3zP-JVXO-N841-vfRv-dM6x-AdacPT]
        Skip sequential IO: 1
        Max Degrade Flush: 0
        APM Flush Done: 0
        Allowed Drop Cache: 0
PV count: 1
VG path: /dev/vg1
VG UUID: [rJ0X3K-x3cp-Zw8G-0f2U-8BU2-D3VN-y1vlMk]
RAID UUID: [e0dbf189:7ea6486d:781cfdbe:7460653e]

****** Syno-Block of /dev/sata6 ******
Version: 7
Capability: 0x2
Features: 1
Space Type: Storage Pool
Space Path: @storage_pool
Reuse ID: [reuse_1]
Descriptions: [raid10]
Volume Description: []
Cross EBox: FALSE
Limited RAID Group: SYNO_24
Cache Info:
        Cache Mode: Read
        Cache Type: SSD Cache
        SSD UUID: [470b94ec:85ecef3e:3244234e:bf658f97]
        Cache size: 429496729600
        Shared Cache ID: 0
        Allocated Cache Sub ID: 0
        SSD ID: 1
        Target Space UUID: [83OFdO-o3zP-JVXO-N841-vfRv-dM6x-AdacPT]
        Skip sequential IO: 1
        Max Degrade Flush: 0
        APM Flush Done: 0
        Allowed Drop Cache: 0
PV count: 1
VG path: /dev/vg1
VG UUID: [rJ0X3K-x3cp-Zw8G-0f2U-8BU2-D3VN-y1vlMk]
RAID UUID: [e0dbf189:7ea6486d:781cfdbe:7460653e]
****** Syno-Block of /dev/nvme0n1 ******
Version: 7
Capability: 0x2
Features: 1
Space Type: SSD Cache
Space Path: 83OFdO-o3zP-JVXO-N841-vfRv-dM6x-AdacPT
Reuse ID: []
Descriptions: []
Volume Description: []
Cross EBox: FALSE
Limited RAID Group: SYNO_12
Cache Info:
        Cache Mode: Read
        Cache Type: SSD Cache
        SSD UUID: [470b94ec:85ecef3e:3244234e:bf658f97]
        Cache size: 429496729600
        Shared Cache ID: 0
        Allocated Cache Sub ID: 0
        SSD ID: 1
        Target Space UUID: [83OFdO-o3zP-JVXO-N841-vfRv-dM6x-AdacPT]
        Skip sequential IO: 1
        Max Degrade Flush: 0
        APM Flush Done: 0
        Allowed Drop Cache: 0
RAID UUID: [470b94ec:85ecef3e:3244234e:bf658f97]

****** Syno-Block of /dev/nvme1n1 ******
Version: 7
Capability: 0x2
Features: 1
Space Type: SSD Cache
Space Path: 83OFdO-o3zP-JVXO-N841-vfRv-dM6x-AdacPT
Reuse ID: []
Descriptions: []
Volume Description: []
Cross EBox: FALSE
Limited RAID Group: SYNO_12
Cache Info:
        Cache Mode: Read
        Cache Type: SSD Cache
        SSD UUID: [470b94ec:85ecef3e:3244234e:bf658f97]
        Cache size: 429496729600
        Shared Cache ID: 0
        Allocated Cache Sub ID: 0
        SSD ID: 1
        Target Space UUID: [83OFdO-o3zP-JVXO-N841-vfRv-dM6x-AdacPT]
        Skip sequential IO: 1
        Max Degrade Flush: 0
        APM Flush Done: 0
        Allowed Drop Cache: 0
RAID UUID: [470b94ec:85ecef3e:3244234e:bf658f97]
****** Syno-Block of /dev/sata7 ******
Version: 7
Capability: 0x2
Features: 1
Space Type: Storage Pool
Space Path: @storage_pool
Reuse ID: [reuse_1]
Descriptions: [raid10]
Volume Description: []
Cross EBox: FALSE
Limited RAID Group: SYNO_24
Cache Info:
        Cache Mode: Read
        Cache Type: SSD Cache
        SSD UUID: [470b94ec:85ecef3e:3244234e:bf658f97]
        Cache size: 429496729600
        Shared Cache ID: 0
        Allocated Cache Sub ID: 0
        SSD ID: 1
        Target Space UUID: [83OFdO-o3zP-JVXO-N841-vfRv-dM6x-AdacPT]
        Skip sequential IO: 1
        Max Degrade Flush: 0
        APM Flush Done: 0
        Allowed Drop Cache: 0
PV count: 1
VG path: /dev/vg1
VG UUID: [rJ0X3K-x3cp-Zw8G-0f2U-8BU2-D3VN-y1vlMk]
RAID UUID: [e0dbf189:7ea6486d:781cfdbe:7460653e]

****** Syno-Block of /dev/sata8 ******
Version: 7
Capability: 0x2
Features: 1
Space Type: Storage Pool
Space Path: @storage_pool
Reuse ID: [reuse_1]
Descriptions: [raid10]
Volume Description: []
Cross EBox: FALSE
Limited RAID Group: SYNO_24
Cache Info:
        Cache Mode: Read
        Cache Type: SSD Cache
        SSD UUID: [470b94ec:85ecef3e:3244234e:bf658f97]
        Cache size: 429496729600
        Shared Cache ID: 0
        Allocated Cache Sub ID: 0
        SSD ID: 1
        Target Space UUID: [83OFdO-o3zP-JVXO-N841-vfRv-dM6x-AdacPT]
        Skip sequential IO: 1
        Max Degrade Flush: 0
        APM Flush Done: 0
        Allowed Drop Cache: 0
PV count: 1
VG path: /dev/vg1
VG UUID: [rJ0X3K-x3cp-Zw8G-0f2U-8BU2-D3VN-y1vlMk]
RAID UUID: [e0dbf189:7ea6486d:781cfdbe:7460653e]

mdadm scan
root@nas:~# mdadm --assemble --scan
mdadm: /dev/md/syn_nas:2 assembled from 3 drives - not enough to start the array.


If you can, as the first step, make a disk image of the failing disks. Use ddrescue or something similar.

I'd love to, but I don't have the storage space (24TB) available to me. I had thought of imaging to backblaze or similar but I have no knowledge of a command-line client I could use.

Then find a paid service which has the necessary storage resources to do this operation. Yes, you need to do this dump as the very first stage.

Ok, great, thanks. What are the steps following that, then?

It's possible to rebuild the RAID superblocks by using the exact same parameters when the superblock was first created.

Thanks @paladin that was my thought too. I can see from the intact superblocks on /dev/sata[1|2|3]p3 that the following params were used:
Data Offset: 2048 sectors
Super Offset: 8 sectors
Layout: near=2
Chunk Size: 64K
Raid Level: raid10
Raid Devices: 8
Hopefully this is all I need. Still researching before I do anything. Also, when I run the smartctl test from my desktop PC, one of the disks with read errors didn't show them. Didn't test all the others yet. I think the nas sata backplane is bust but the disks and data (apart from the dodgy sectors) is intact.

Creating a safety backup, as already suggested by others, should be done by you. Also keep in mind that maybe other data, beside the superblocks, might be destroyed too, and regenerating data by using backups is recommended.
